# How to find intersection time of multiple time periods?

Tags: mysql, sql

How we can find the **intersection time** of multiple times in mysql? I have this table:

#### Input:

```
id | circuit_id |  downtime       |  uptime         | duration | Location
---+------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+----------
 1 |      1     | 6/12/2019 11:22 | 6/12/2019 11:27 |  0:05:00 | Bhopal
 2 |      2     | 6/12/2019 04:55 | 6/12/2019 07:19 |  2:24:00 | Bhopal
 3 |      3     | 6/04/2019 17:59 | 6/06/2019 18:57 | 48:58:00 | Bhopal
 4 |      4     | 6/02/2019 03:06 | 6/02/2019 03:12 |  0:06:00 | Bhopal
 5 |      1     | 6/01/2019 19:49 | 6/01/2019 20:00 |  0:11:00 | Bhopal
 6 |      2     | 5/24/2019 14:59 | 5/24/2019 15:03 |  0:04:00 | Bhopal
 7 |      3     | 5/19/2019 03:15 | 5/19/2019 03:54 |  0:39:00 | Bhopal
 8 |      4     | 5/15/2019 19:47 | 5/15/2019 19:50 |  0:03:00 | Bhopal
 9 |      1     | 5/10/2019 01:21 | 5/10/2019 03:52 |  0:31:00 | Bhopal
10 |      2     | 5/10/2019 02:55 | 5/10/2019 03:37 |  2:42:00 | Bhopal
11 |      3     | 5/10/2019 03:18 | 5/10/2019 04:37 |  1:19:00 | Bhopal
12 |      4     | 5/10/2019 03:20 | 5/10/2019 03:30 |  1:25:00 | Bhopal
13 |      1     | 5/09/2019 05:06 | 5/09/2019 14:17 |  9:11:00 | Bhopal
14 |      2     | 5/09/2019 04:31 | 5/09/2019 04:34 |  0:03:00 | Bhopal
15 |      3     | 4/17/2019 18:37 | 4/17/2019 18:44 |  0:07:00 | Bhopal
16 |      6     | 4/17/2019 17:23 | 4/17/2019 18:05 |  0:42:00 | Delhi
17 |      7     | 4/17/2019 17:00 | 4/17/2019 17:05 |  0:05:00 | Delhi
18 |      8     | 4/10/2019 06:16 | 4/10/2019 06:22 |  0:06:00 | Delhi
19 |      9     | 4/10/2019 02:20 | 4/10/2019 02:45 |  0:25:00 | Delhi
20 |      6     | 4/08/2019 23:01 | 4/08/2019 23:05 |  0:04:00 | Delhi
21 |      7     | 4/05/2019 11:20 | 4/05/2019 11:27 |  0:07:00 | Delhi
22 |      8     | 4/04/2019 01:16 | 4/04/2019 01:27 |  0:11:00 | Delhi
23 |      9     | 4/02/2019 16:30 | 4/02/2019 16:31 |  0:01:00 | Delhi
```

How to check date-wise and location-wise which is the overlap of times? If all circuits are down within the same time span, then treat it as down, otherwise as up. I only need downtime data.

#### Expected output:

Bhopal on 05/10/2019 is down for ten minutes 00:10, as all four circuits are down between 03:20 to 03:30 on that particular day.

```
Location | downtime | date
---------+----------+-----------
Bhopal   |  00:10   | 2019-05-10
```

Comment: So, you're looking for the shortest time period that is completely within another time period?

Comment: I want to common time when all link are down.

Comment: Why not 1:30? Or 1:35?

Comment: From 1:30 to 1:40 our all link are down. So I need this

Comment: What should happen if a 5th record with link 'e' has a period completely outside of the other periods? Or do you have a limited (4?) number of links and you want all periods during which all these links were down?

Comment: There is no effect we are finding common time. For example we are taking 4 for example. What is the query for finding common time between these four data

Comment: Please also add the expected output for the sample data you have given.

Comment: I have put all above.

Comment: I want to those unique records which have down same time in a single day on particular location

Comment: So what happens if the overlap passes across midnight from one day to the next?

Comment: We are only take same date data. If next day will be same count on next day

Comment: No. of circuit Id of multiple on same date but not more then 4 unique.

Comment: So is it impossible that `downtime` and `update` value of the *same* record are on *different* days?

Comment: Yes so we are only take same day data.

Comment: If overlap passes across midnight then we will treat till 23:00 as a downtime

Comment: What if a certain circuit is *never* down: then it will not appear in that table, but then you also don't know that *all* circuits are down. How will you solve that? Do you have a separate table with all the circuits per location?

Comment: According to our this table all (4) circuit id appear in same date and same time this only treat as downtime. Otherwise not treat as downtime

Comment: You only have four circuits? Where do I see that in your sample data? I see 23 different circuit_id...

Comment: Can you help me for writing query location and day wise downtime. The condition is if 4 link appears in same time period (same date time) then selected

Comment: Yes we have four circuit id in a single location

Comment: I have correct it. In Bhopal have 4 circuit id and Delhi have 4 circuit id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a self-join to match overlaps, and a `having` clause to filter for those that include all links.

To get the total number of circuits, you could do another self-join to find all circuits that have ever appeared in the table, per location:

```
select     a.location, 
           num_circuits, 
           a.downtime, 
           min(b.uptime) uptime, 
           timediff(min(b.uptime), a.downtime) duration, 
           count(distinct b.circuit_id) num_circuits_down
from       tbl a
inner join tbl b 
        on a.location = b.location
       and a.downtime between b.downtime and b.uptime
inner join (
            select   location, count(distinct circuit_id) num_circuits
            from     tbl
            group by location
           ) c
        on a.location = c.location
group by   a.location, num_circuits, a.downtime
having     count(distinct b.circuit_id) = num_circuits;
```

It would be better to have a separate reference-table which lists the circuits per location (4 records per location in your case). 
Then the above query would select from that reference table, so instead of:

```
            select   location, count(distinct circuit_id) num_circuits
            from     tbl
            group by location
```

... you would do:

```
            select   location, count(distinct circuit_id) num_circuits
            from     reftable
            group by location
```

That will make the above query more efficient and reliable.

Comment: Thank yo so much. What is the role of having clause?

Comment: I have 4 link of this location but only one is down. this also showing. If count is 4 then how to eliminate single data from downtime.

Comment: id   link      dt_time_from        dt_time_to                location
1     a        19-Apr 01:00:00     19-Apr 03:00:00     Delhi
2     b        19-Apr 01:15:00     19-Apr 01:45:00     Delhi
3     c        19-Apr 01:20:00     19-Apr 01:40:00     Rajasthan
4     d        19-Apr 01:30:00     19-Apr 01:40:00    Rajasthan   . I have 4 link of Delhi and  Rajasthan. So if Delhi showing 2 times then Delhi need not come in query

Comment: My question is if I have 4 link in some location and 2 only show in above example then this shouldn't come in query.

Comment: So you only want to show the common downtime when the location is the same for all 4 links? Then just add the location field in the `select`, `join...on` and `group by` clauses.

Comment: Yes but my problem still not resolved fully. I am trying join with multiple tables

Comment: I updated my answer in line with your updated question.

Comment: Could you give some feedback?

Comment: Suppose I have 2 or 3 link and all are down to where we can change

Comment: You should create that reference table giving the count of links per location. The query will retrieve that count and compare it with the down-count